# fmt::Debug a number field with differing base (rust)

Tags: rust

I want to the `Debug` format of a struct number field to show a decimal value and a hexadecimal value.

So given rust `struct` ([rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=beta&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bd3dd3192bc3a8db643bcbc190a15f85))

```rust
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct S1 {
    pub num1: u64,
}

fn main() {
    let mut s1 = S1::default();
    s1.num1 = 0xFF;
    println!("{:?}", s1)
}
```

I would like `fmt::Debug` implementation (i.e. format string `"{:?}"`) to show two different based values for field `num1`, i.e. to print

```text
S1 { num1: 255 (0xFF) }
```

(I'm not sure how to solve the easier problem: format the numeric field as hexadecimal).

---

Here is what I have for `fmt::Debug` implementation

```rust
impl std::fmt::Debug for S1 {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        f.debug_struct("S1")
            .field("num1", &self.num1)
            .finish()
    }
}
```

I do not know which part of `std::fmt` module would help me.

Comment: You could just format!() the field instead of using it with debug_struct helper directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `format_args!` to construct the formatting arguments in a low-cost way:

```
impl std::fmt::Debug for S1 {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        f.debug_struct("S1")
            .field("num1", &format_args!("{0:?} (0x{0:X})", &self.num1))
            .finish()
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh gosh, well that was really easy! Thanks!  In my defense, I was confused about the expectations for the `field` arguments. The `field` argument signature includes last argument [`value: &dyn Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/alloc/fmt/struct.DebugStruct.html#method.field), which, in my mind, created an infinite loop of `Debug` implementations... 

Comment: It would indeed, if you passed `self` there.